# Inaccuracy in number->string in Scheme

Tags: numbers, scheme, numeric

I am working on a Scheme program, where I need at some place a pair of a floatingpoint counter and the same counter as formated string. I am having issues with the number to string conversion.

Can someone explain me these inaccuracies in this code ?

```
(letrec ((ground-loop (lambda (times count step)
             (if (= times 250)
              (begin
                (display "exit")
                (newline)
              ) 
              (begin 
                  (display (* times step)) (newline)
                  (display (number->string  (* times step)))(newline)
                  (newline)
                  (newline)
                  (ground-loop (+ times 1) (* times step) step)
                )
             )
          )
))
  (ground-loop 0 0 0.05)
)
```

Part of the output looks like that

> 7.25
>   7.25
>
> 7.3
>   7.300000000000001
>
> 7.35
>   7.350000000000001
>
> 7.4
>   7.4
>
> 7.45
>   7.45
>
> 7.5
>   7.5
>
> 7.55
>   7.550000000000001
>
> 7.6
>   7.600000000000001
>
> 7.65
>   7.65

I am aware of floating point inaccuracies and tried several forms of increasing the counter but the issue is in the conversion itself.

Any ideas for an easy fix? Tried a bit with explicitly rounded numbers but this did not do the job. The results even vary from IDE and environment to environment. Do I really have to do string manipulation after conversion?
The very weird thing in my case is having an exact numeric result but the string is off.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if:

- the native float type (the type you get by reading `1.0`) of your implementation is IEEE double float;
- the `display` of your Scheme is not printing such floats 'correctly' (see below, I'm no sure this means it's buggy);
- your `number->string` *is* doing the right thing.

By 'correctly' above I mean 'in a way so that reading what `display` printed returns an equivalent number'.  I am not at all sure that `display` is *required* to be correct in this restrictive sense however, so I am not sure whether it's a bug.  Someone who understands the Scheme standards better than I do might be able to comment on that.

In particular if the native float type of the languageis an IEEE double float, then, for instance:

```
(= (* 0.05 3) 0.15)
```

is false, as is

```
(= (* 0.05 146) 7.3)
```

Which is the example you have in the first line of your output.

So you certainly should not assume that your program will ever produce a number equal to the number you get by reading `7.3` for instance, because it won't.

In the above I have carefully avoided printing the numbers out, and that's because I'm not sure `display` is reliable on this, and in particular I'm not sure *your* `display` is reliable or that it is required to be.

Well, I have a Lisp implementation to hand which *is* reliable about this.  In this system the default float format is a single-precision IEEE float, and I can get the reader to read double floats with, for instance `1.0d0`.  So, in this implementation you can see the results:

```
> (* 0.05d0 3)
0.15000000000000002D0

> (* 0.05d0 146)
7.300000000000001D0
```

And you'll see that these are exactly (up to the double-precision indicator) what `number->string` is giving you and *not* what `display` is giving you.

If what you want to do is to get a representation of the number in such a way that reading it will return an equivalent number, then `number->string` is what you should trust.  In particular [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) says in section 6.2.6 that:

```
(let ((number number)
      (radix radix))
  (eqv? number
        (string->number (number->string number
                                        radix)
                        radix)))
```

is true, and 'it is an error if no possible result makes this expression true'.

You can check the behaviour of `number->float` & `float->number` over a range of numbers by, for instance (this may assume a more recent or featurefull Scheme than you have):

```
(define (verify-float-conversion base times)
  (define (good? f)
    (eqv? (string->number (number->string f)) f))
  (let loop ([i 0]
             [bads '()])
    (let ([c (* base i)])
      (if (>= i times)
          (values (null? bads) (reverse bads))
          (loop (+ i 1) (if (good? c) bads (cons c bads)))))))
```

Then you should get

```
> (verify-float-conversion 0.05 10000)
#t
()
```

More generally using floats, still more floats that are the result of some computation more complicated than reading them some input source, as unique indices into any kind of tabular structure is fraught with danger to put it rather mildly: floating-point errors mean that it's just really dangerous to assume that `(= a b)` is true for floats even when it mathematically should be.

If you want such indices do exact arithmetic instead, and convert the results of that arithmetic to floats at the point you need to do computations.  I believe (but am not sure) that Scheme implementations are nowadays required to support exact rational arithmetic (certainly this seems to be true for R6RS), so if you want to count 20ths (say) you can do so by counting in units of `1/20`, which is exact, and then constructing floats when you need them.

It's probably safe to compare floats in the case that if you are for instance comparing a float you got by taking some initial float value and multiplying it by a machine integer and comparing it with some earlier version of itself which you have read by `string->number`.  But if the calculation your doing is more complicated than that you need to be quite careful.

Comment: Thank You very much! Your answer clarified a lot of questions in my mind about this topic. Appreciate your time! I am currently trying to figure out which exact environment I have to at least have some kind of reliable documentation. I am not shure if I get the point of the last paragraph correctly. Basically you say never compare a float with another float you read in. Always compute the float when you need it even if it looks quite complicated? But what options do I have then? Increasing the counter by 5 and deviding by 100 is not exact, too

Comment: @blackbaddl: what I'm really saying is that comparing floats for exact equality is just a very dangerous endeavour *unless* you are doing it in a very constrained way, since there rounding errors are just pervasive.  However in Scheme (at least any R6RS-compliant one) you *can* do exact arithmetic on rationals: `(= (* (/ 1 20) 3) (/ 3 20))` should be true, always.

Comment: FYI I got answer from a developer of the software I am using. I am dealing with "a sheme version somewhere between MIT 3 and MIT 4"